# Is there any way to resize input shapes in SNPE (dlc)?

Tags: tensorflow, dynamic, resize, snpe

I have trained a model based on Tensorflow. This model is supposed to work on the mobile phone but I have got a problem when converting froze graph (pb) to deep learning container(dlc). I have to set the input size to be constant. This cause that model can't work with any input size.
I am trying to find a way that resizes input shapes of a DLC model without initializing model with "snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc --input_dims 1,512,512,3" because this way is consuming. 
Actually, I want to resize input shapes in dlc model. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Usually deployment solutions work with fixed input shapes because they assume some widely acknowledged usage model - resize all picture of the same certain size and do inference. And due to this usage model, developers of deployment solutions do not prioritize model loading time while they usually prioritize the inference time. The same happens in SNPE, in OpenVINO, in TFLite, etc.

To illustrate the times, here is some results from Snapdragon 820. To load Inception v3 to CPU takes 715ms, to load model to DSP takes 3 seconds. Inference on CPU takes 1 sec, inference on DSP takes 100ms. You see that loading time on DSP is bigger than on CPU, but inference time is much much better.

At the same time, usually it is allowed to change a shape before loading of the model assuming that all input pictures will have different size (but again, same for all pictures) than shapes for which model was trained. For SNPE it is [SNPEBuilder::setInputDimensions](https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/group__c__plus__plus__apis.html#abb432cbbc740c42ea942d886b9c1c53e)
If model allow to do reshape and if no bugs in SNPE implementation, the model can be reshaped and loaded.

Not sure if your usage model fits to the vision described in the first paragraph. At the same time, to have a benefit from different input size you need to develop special topology that unlikely be supported by SNPE. If you take just regular SSD and reshape it to different size and measure accuracy on validation set, the most likely you get the best result on shpaes where model was trained.